# Replacement for Delete method in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find out the **replacement** for Delete method in jquery/javascript as I am **not** able to use **delete method** in **IE11**. IE gives out an error **object doesn't support this property or method 'delete'.**

I am trying to replace the following code:

```
formData.delete($(this).closest('.text-center').find('.imageUrl').attr("name"));
```

I want to replace the delete method with any other method that is supported by IE.

Comment: Where is the `formData` variable coming from?  Something like `formData = document.query('form')` or `formData = $('form')`?

Comment: What is `formData` here ?

Comment: looks like the ONLY method IE `FormData` has is `append` - you may have to create a new `FormData` only copying the entries you require - and with no way to see what has been added already, good luck

Comment: Hey @ethan, formData variable is  -                                                              var formData = new FormData($form[0]);

Answer (score 0):

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/FormData), there's nearly no support for `FormData` in Internet Explorer (*nearly* still being optimistic: It only supports `append`). The proposed answer of fubar using `delete ...` won't work here, since:

```
a = new FormData()
a.set('foo', 'bar')
a.get('foo') // "bar"
a['foo'] // undefined
delete a['foo'] // true
a.get('foo') // still "bar"
```

So, after a little brainstorming my first idea would be: Create a copy of the FormData object without the key which should be deleted (foreach key-value pairs). But: This won't work either since IE has no support for [entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/entries) and any other possibility (`Object.keys` and friends) does not work in my test.

I would suggest, either: Use a Polyfill, like this: [FormData polyfill](https://github.com/jimmywarting/FormData).

Or (which I would prefer according to your example): You could consider not using FormData after all. Since the constructor `FormData(form)` just fills the object with key-value pairs taken from the form (the `name` attribute being the key), you may implement this behaviour with plain old JavaScript objects like so, being then able to use anything known from objects (`Object.keys`, `delete` etc.).

```js
function formData(form) {
  var result = {};

  $(form).children('input').each(function (i, elem) {
    result[elem.name] = elem.value;
  });
  
  return result;
}

var data = formData($('#my-form'));

console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

delete data['pet'];

console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="my-form">
  <input type="text"
         value="Jon"
         name="name" />
  <input type="text"
        value="kitty"
        name="pet" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw that IE did not support any other method of FormData other than append, so the delete method will not work. Hence, I removed the delete method and solved the problem only by using append.

Thank you for all the responses.